Problems with diminishing particle diameter and increasing time step for a simulation of volcanic ashes
I am rather new to Mathematica, and I have been tasked with a project to attempt to simulate the trajectory of volcanic ash particles. In the long term, I am trying to simulate particles of diameters close to 25-50*10^-6, with a timeStep at around 60s, and seeing how the particles move with the wind. However, I am having major issues when it comes to increasing time steps and diminishing the diameter of the particles
Now my main issue comes within the trajectory/geoTrajectory, with the output breaking as follows.
{63.6349, -19.6113, 3000}, {63.6349, -19.6113, 2999.92} ... {63.766, -19.6569, 1431.76}, {340236., 165746., -3.1132*10^9}
I understand that this is most likely due to the way that I am accounting for the sum of the windForces, but I have not found another way that has worked so far. If anyone could help me figure out my issue, it would be great.
I have also provided my full code for replication
gridPoints = Flatten[data[[9, 87 ;; 95, 23 ;; 45, 1, 1, 1]], 1];
windForces = Flatten[data[[9, 87 ;; 95, 23 ;; 45, 1, 2]], 1];
arrows = MapThread[With[{degreeChange = convertForceToDegrees[#2, #1[[1]]]}, Arrow[{GeoPosition[#1], GeoPosition[{#1[[1]] + degreeChange[[1]], #1[[2]] + degreeChange[[2]], #1[[3]]}]}]] &, {gridPoints, windForces}];

geoGridPoints = data[[9, 87 ;; 95, 23 ;; 45, 1, 1]]; 

refLat = 63.63509;
refLon = -19.61262;

numParticles = 1;
timeStep = 0.1;
totalTime = 3600;

particleDensity = 1400; 
fluidViscosity = 1.81*10^-5;
fluidDensity = 1.225;
altitudeMT = {2000, 3000};
particleVelocities = Table[{0.0, 0.0, 0.0}, {numParticles}];
particleAccelerations = Table[{0.0, 0.0, 0.0}, {numParticles}];
particleDiameters = RandomReal[{0.0330, 0.0335}, numParticles];
particleRadii = particleDiameters/2;
particleMasses = particleDensity*(4/3)*Pi*particleRadii^3;
diameterToAltitude[diameter_] := If[diameter > 0.1, altitudeMT[[1]], altitudeMT[[2]]]; 
particleStartAltitudes = diameterToAltitude /@ particleDiameters;
particlePositions = Table[{refLat, refLon, particleStartAltitudes[[i]]}, {i, numParticles}];

LaunchKernels[];
metersPerDegreeLat = 111320;
metersPerDegreeLon[lat_] := Cos[lat*Degree]*metersPerDegreeLat;  
convertForceToDegrees[{fx_, fy_, _}, lat_] := Module[{dx, dy, earthRadius = 6371000, latToMeters, lonToMeters}, latToMeters = earthRadius*Pi/180; lonToMeters = latToMeters*Cos[lat*Degree]; dx = fx/lonToMeters; dy = fy/latToMeters; {dy, dx}];

convertToGeo[{xMeters_, yMeters_, z_}, latRef_, lonRef_] := Module[{latDeg, lonDeg},latDeg = yMeters/metersPerDegreeLat;lonDeg = xMeters/metersPerDegreeLon[latRef];{latRef + latDeg, lonRef + lonDeg, z}];

totalAcceleration[particleIndex_] := Module[{gravitationalAcceleration, dragForce, dragCoefficient, dragAcceleration, windForce, windAcceleration}, gravitationalAcceleration = {0, 0, -9.81};
dragCoefficient = dynamicDragCoefficient[particleVelocities[[particleIndex]], particleIndex];
dragForce = 0.5*dragCoefficient*Norm[particleVelocities[[particleIndex]]]^2* Normalize[particleVelocities[[particleIndex]]];
dragAcceleration = dragForce/particleMasses[[particleIndex]];
windForce = gridForces[particlePositions[[particleIndex]], gridPoints, windForces];
windAcceleration = windForce/particleMasses[[particleIndex]];
gravitationalAcceleration + windAcceleration - dragAcceleration];

gridForces[particlePosition_, gridPoints_, forces_] := Module[{distances, sortedIndices, nearestFourIndices, weights, weightedForces, altitudeFactor, epsilon = 1.*^-10, maxForceComponent}, 
distances = Map[Norm[particlePosition - #] + epsilon &, gridPoints];
sortedIndices = Ordering[distances];
nearestFourIndices = Take[sortedIndices, 4];
weights = 1/(distances[[nearestFourIndices]]);
weights /= Total[weights]; 
weightedForces = Total[MapThread[Times, {weights, forces[[nearestFourIndices]]}]]; 
altitudeFactor = 1 - (particlePosition[[3]] - Min[altitudeMT])/(Max[altitudeMT] - Min[altitudeMT]);
maxForceComponent = Max[Abs[weightedForces]]*altitudeFactor; If[maxForceComponent > 100.0, weightedForces *= 100.0/maxForceComponent]; weightedForces];

particleTrajectory[particleIndex_, dt_] := Module[{k1v, k1p, k2v, k2p, k3v, k3p, k4v, k4p, newPosition, newVelocity}, 
k1v = totalAcceleration[particleIndex]*dt;
k1p = particleVelocities[[particleIndex]]*dt;
particlePositions[[particleIndex]] += k1p/2;
particleVelocities[[particleIndex]] += k1v/2;
k2v = totalAcceleration[particleIndex]*dt;
k2p = particleVelocities[[particleIndex]]*dt;
particlePositions[[particleIndex]] += k2p/2;
particleVelocities[[particleIndex]] += k2v/2;
k3v = totalAcceleration[particleIndex]*dt;
k3p = particleVelocities[[particleIndex]]*dt;
particlePositions[[particleIndex]] += k3p;
particleVelocities[[particleIndex]] += k3v;
k4v = totalAcceleration[particleIndex]*dt;
k4p = particleVelocities[[particleIndex]]*dt;
newVelocity = particleVelocities[[particleIndex]] + (k1v + 2*k2v + 2*k3v + k4v)/ 6;
newPosition = particlePositions[[particleIndex]] + (k1p + 2*k2p + 2*k3p + k4p)/6;
particlePositions[[particleIndex]] = newPosition;
particleVelocities[[particleIndex]] = newVelocity;];

trajectories = ParallelTable[Reap[Sow[particlePositions[[i]]]; 
 Do[particleTrajectory[i, timeStep]; Sow[particlePositions[[i]]]; 
  If[particlePositions[[i, 3]] <= 0, Break[]], {step, 1, 
   Round[totalTime/timeStep]}]][[2, 1]], {i, numParticles}];

dynamicDragCoefficient[velocity_, particleIndex_] := Module[{Re, speed, localParticleDiameter, dragCoefficient, minSpeed = 10^-6}, 
speed = Norm[velocity];
localParticleDiameter = particleDiameters[[particleIndex]];
If[speed < minSpeed, dragCoefficient = 240, 
Re = (fluidDensity*Max[speed, minSpeed]*localParticleDiameter)/ fluidViscosity;
dragCoefficient = Which[Re < 0.1, 240, 0.1 <= Re < 0.2, 12/Re, 0.2 <= Re < 1000, 24/Re*(1 + 0.15*Re^0.687), 1000 <= Re < 2*10^5, 0.44, 2*10^5 <= Re, 0.1]];
dragCoefficient];

DistributeDefinitions[particleTrajectory, totalAcceleration, dynamicDragCoefficient, particlePositions, particleVelocities, particleAccelerations, gridPoints, windForces];

CloseKernels[];

geoTrajectories = Map[convertToGeo[#, refLat, refLon] &, trajectories, {2}];
lastPositions = Last /@ geoTrajectories;
GeoGraphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[GeoPosition[{refLat, refLon}]], {Black, PointSize[Medium], Point[GeoPosition[#]] & /@ lastPositions} }, GeoRange -> {{63, 67}, {-26, -12}}, ImageSize -> Large, Frame -> True, GeoGridLines -> Automatic]
GeoGraphics[{{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[GeoPosition[{refLat, refLon}]]}, {Black, Arrowheads[0.01], arrows}, {Blue, PointSize[Small], Point[GeoPosition /@ gridPoints]}}, GeoRange -> {{63, 67}, {-26, -12}}, ImageSize -> Large, Frame -> True, GeoGridLines -> Automatic]

gridPoints Data: {{63., -26.25, 1664.01}, {63., -25.625, 1663.36}, {63., -25., 1662.51}, {63., -24.375, 1662.77}, {63., -23.75, 1663.03}, {63., -23.125, 1662.32}, {63., -22.5, 1662.16}, {63., -21.875, 1663.04}, {63., -21.25, 1663.7}, {63., -20.625, 1664.24}, {63., -20., 1663.64}, {63., -19.375, 1663.3}, {63., -18.75, 1664.52}, {63., -18.125, 1665.67}, {63., -17.5, 1666.16}, {63., -16.875, 1666.34}, {63., -16.25, 1667.05}, {63., -15.625, 1668.16}, {63., -15., 1669.75}, {63., -14.375, 1672.06}, {63., -13.75, 1674.65}, {63., -13.125, 1676.88}, {63., -12.5, 1679.23}, {63.5, -26.25, 1669.32}, {63.5, -25.625, 1668.43}, {63.5, -25., 1668.08}, {63.5, -24.375, 1668.87}, {63.5, -23.75, 1668.66}, {63.5, -23.125, 1667.34}, {63.5, -22.5, 1668.32}, {63.5, -21.875, 1670.5}, {63.5, -21.25, 1667.78}, {63.5, -20.625, 1665.21}, {63.5, -20., 1669.13}, {63.5, -19.375, 1671.19}, {63.5, -18.75, 1671.77}, {63.5, -18.125, 1672.22}, {63.5, -17.5, 1673.12}, {63.5, -16.875, 1675.03}, {63.5, -16.25, 1677.13}, {63.5, -15.625, 1678.46}, {63.5, -15., 1679.47}, {63.5, -14.375, 1680.26}, {63.5, -13.75, 1681.1}, {63.5, -13.125, 1682.94}, {63.5, -12.5, 1685.14}, {64., -26.25, 1674.7}, {64., -25.625, 1674.04}, {64., -25., 1674.49}, {64., -24.375, 1675.06}, {64., -23.75, 1674.32}, {64., -23.125, 1673.73}, {64., -22.5, 1675.3}, {64., -21.875, 1676.59}, {64., -21.25, 1675.85}, {64., -20.625, 1674.54}, {64., -20., 1674.67}, {64., -19.375, 1675.63}, {64., -18.75, 1676.51}, {64., -18.125, 1677.54}, {64., -17.5, 1677.3}, {64., -16.875, 1678.54}, {64., -16.25, 1679.93}, {64., -15.625, 1681.37}, {64., -15., 1683.04}, {64., -14.375, 1686.03}, {64., -13.75, 1688.71}, {64., -13.125, 1689.96}, {64., -12.5, 1691.8}, {64.5, -26.25, 1681.82}, {64.5, -25.625, 1681.44}, {64.5, -25., 1681.35}, {64.5, -24.375, 1681.28}, {64.5, -23.75, 1681.11}, {64.5, -23.125, 1681.14}, {64.5, -22.5, 1681.14}, {64.5, -21.875, 1679.74}, {64.5, -21.25, 1678.1}, {64.5, -20.625, 1680.66}, {64.5, -20., 1682.88}, {64.5, -19.375, 1681.55}, {64.5, -18.75, 1679.93}, {64.5, -18.125, 1682.57}, {64.5, -17.5, 1686.22}, {64.5, -16.875, 1689.55}, {64.5, -16.25, 1693.11}, {64.5, -15.625, 1696.38}, {64.5, -15., 1697.68}, {64.5, -14.375, 1695.27}, {64.5, -13.75, 1695.11}, {64.5, -13.125, 1697.68}, {64.5, -12.5, 1699.27}, {65., -26.25, 1689.33}, {65., -25.625, 1688.73}, {65., -25., 1688.28}, {65., -24.375, 1688.32}, {65., -23.75, 1688.17}, {65., -23.125, 1688.77}, {65., -22.5, 1689.68}, {65., -21.875, 1689.27}, {65., -21.25, 1688.32}, {65., -20.625, 1687.88}, {65., -20., 1688.65}, {65., -19.375, 1689.22}, {65., -18.75, 1690.14}, {65., -18.125, 1691.41}, {65., -17.5, 1691.8}, {65., -16.875, 1691.99}, {65., -16.25, 1692.87}, {65., -15.625, 1694.68}, {65., -15., 1698.03}, {65., -14.375, 1702.61}, {65., -13.75, 1704.18}, {65., -13.125, 1704.07}, {65., -12.5, 1705.66}, {65.5, -26.25, 1697.63}, {65.5, -25.625, 1696.73}, {65.5, -25., 1696.36}, {65.5, -24.375, 1696.63}, {65.5, -23.75, 1695.78}, {65.5, -23.125, 1693.73}, {65.5, -22.5, 1694.28}, {65.5, -21.875, 1696.18}, {65.5, -21.25, 1696.69}, {65.5, -20.625, 1696.1}, {65.5, -20., 1695.97}, {65.5, -19.375, 1696.25}, {65.5, -18.75, 1698.}, {65.5, -18.125, 1701.22}, {65.5, -17.5, 1702.93}, {65.5, -16.875, 1703.88}, {65.5, -16.25, 1704.91}, {65.5, -15.625, 1705.68}, {65.5, -15., 1706.92}, {65.5, -14.375, 1708.38}, {65.5, -13.75, 1709.56}, {65.5, -13.125, 1710.66}, {65.5, -12.5, 1712.43}, {66., -26.25, 1706.07}, {66., -25.625, 1705.48}, {66., -25., 1704.74}, {66., -24.375, 1703.82}, {66., -23.75, 1703.47}, {66., -23.125, 1703.76}, {66., -22.5, 1705.44}, {66., -21.875, 1706.85}, {66., -21.25, 1705.35}, {66., -20.625, 1704.39}, {66., -20., 1705.2}, {66., -19.375, 1706.13}, {66., -18.75, 1706.8}, {66., -18.125, 1707.17}, {66., -17.5, 1707.02}, {66., -16.875, 1706.7}, {66., -16.25, 1708.93}, {66., -15.625, 1711.56}, {66., -15., 1712.79}, {66., -14.375, 1713.98}, {66., -13.75, 1716.06}, {66., -13.125, 1718.19}, {66., -12.5, 1719.21}, {66.5, -26.25, 1715.47}, {66.5, -25.625, 1714.8}, {66.5, -25., 1714.54}, {66.5, -24.375, 1713.61}, {66.5, -23.75, 1712.07}, {66.5, -23.125, 1711.54}, {66.5, -22.5, 1712.15}, {66.5, -21.875, 1712.96}, {66.5, -21.25, 1713.32}, {66.5, -20.625, 1713.39}, {66.5, -20., 1713.63}, {66.5, -19.375, 1713.98}, {66.5, -18.75, 1714.75}, {66.5, -18.125, 1715.87}, {66.5, -17.5, 1717.09}, {66.5, -16.875, 1718.15}, {66.5, -16.25, 1718.31}, {66.5, -15.625, 1718.67}, {66.5, -15., 1720.26}, {66.5, -14.375, 1721.81}, {66.5, -13.75, 1722.85}, {66.5, -13.125, 1724.04}, {66.5, -12.5, 1725.81}, {67., -26.25, 1725.26}, {67., -25.625, 1724.29}, {67., -25., 1723.37}, {67., -24.375, 1723.11}, {67., -23.75, 1723.15}, {67., -23.125, 1722.96}, {67., -22.5, 1722.75}, {67., -21.875, 1721.82}, {67., -21.25, 1721.36}, {67., -20.625, 1721.65}, {67., -20., 1722.09}, {67., -19.375, 1722.33}, {67., -18.75, 1722.27}, {67., -18.125, 1722.48}, {67., -17.5, 1722.92}, {67., -16.875, 1723.62}, {67., -16.25, 1724.64}, {67., -15.625, 1725.79}, {67., -15., 1727.05}, {67., -14.375, 1728.4}, {67., -13.75, 1729.76}, {67., -13.125, 1731.21}, {67., -12.5, 1732.91}}

windData: {{-0.476212, 2.31018, 0.00407593}, {-0.458334, 2.47569, 0.00401368}, {-0.471592, 2.62245, 0.00389868}, {-0.40952, 2.79652, 0.00428251}, {-0.350587, 2.96785, 0.00470401}, {-0.427366, 3.08999, 0.00452405}, {-0.475798, 3.22052, 0.00488063}, {-0.454365, 3.38463, 0.00677639}, {-0.484047, 3.4683, 0.00808652}, {-0.563002, 3.47929, 0.00896809}, {-0.60781, 3.37093, 0.00842172}, {-0.638688, 3.24669, 0.00767903}, {-0.537578, 3.20149, 0.00870156}, {-0.43763, 3.13278, 0.00930404}, {-0.355921, 3.00625, 0.00871447}, {-0.226212, 2.85098, 0.00742509}, {-0.040256, 2.73374, 0.00592891}, {0.170148, 2.72592, 0.0049655}, {0.391785, 2.81043, 0.00453537}, {0.568151, 2.95753, 0.00438091}, {0.727206, 3.1203, 0.00436491}, {0.87716, 3.26939, 0.00390416}, {1.02015, 3.40936, 0.00338765}, {-1.09651, 2.26534, 0.00436185}, {-1.09727, 2.44715, 0.00416157}, {-1.06729, 2.62594, 0.00428378}, {-0.966915, 2.81834, 0.00494303}, {-0.960813, 2.99513, 0.00515621}, {-1.0661, 3.14163, 0.00486975}, {-1.0266, 3.28626, 0.00737117}, {-0.900478, 3.43745, 0.011173}, {-1.03077, 3.57517, 0.0112816}, {-1.20224, 3.68164, 0.0109817}, {-1.5617, 3.56007, 0.00596019}, {-1.70125, 3.38017, 0.00368209}, {-1.29078, 3.18671, 0.00924467}, {-1.0655, 3.05546, 0.0131116}, {-1.05294, 3.01002, 0.0154004}, {-0.936304, 2.91405, 0.0147096}, {-0.744633, 2.77278, 0.0121683}, {-0.48163, 2.7282, 0.010546}, {-0.20587, 2.67484, 0.00848774}, {0.0270441, 2.74845, 0.00622257}, {0.254094, 2.83645, 0.00425412}, {0.438717, 3.0191, 0.00350589}, {0.60695, 3.19054, 0.00299278}, {-1.75555, 2.15914, 0.00446586}, {-1.70217, 2.37402, 0.00431593}, {-1.60411, 2.58643, 0.00486516}, {-1.50608, 2.79169, 0.00550211}, {-1.48723, 3.006, 0.00588517}, {-1.48148, 3.22656, 0.00627382}, {-1.42115, 3.47336, 0.00847162}, {-1.37756, 3.65672, 0.0103938}, {-1.42584, 3.76341, 0.0102906}, {-1.53152, 3.86586, 0.0086929}, {-1.75383, 3.93786, 0.00445988}, {-1.89121, 3.81429, 0.00238561}, {-1.79365, 3.52867, 0.00400662}, {-1.88408, 3.00447, 0.00347204}, {-2.00365, 2.43667, 0.00264168}, {-1.5622, 1.99433, 0.00206322}, {-1.12561, 1.59899, 0.000524109}, {-0.749487, 1.82732, 0.00655557}, {-0.439456, 2.04089, 0.0108418}, {-0.298949, 2.2678, 0.010287}, {-0.120804, 2.49176, 0.00835628}, {0.129741, 2.71622, 0.00488536}, {0.311548, 2.92466, 0.0030647}, {-2.37186, 2.02762, 0.00497923}, {-2.25284, 2.25049, 0.00512472}, {-2.13675, 2.46624, 0.00544676}, {-2.03088, 2.68253, 0.00607583}, {-1.9355, 2.89887, 0.00714681}, {-1.77584, 3.14996, 0.00835783}, {-1.58361, 3.43709, 0.00973066}, {-1.60694, 3.62843, 0.00603623}, {-1.69766, 3.78397, 0.00133615}, {-1.75823, 3.79874, -0.00254948}, {-1.79722, 3.81254, -0.00599148}, {-1.87039, 3.70249, -0.0089527}, {-2.00681, 3.55927, -0.0121924}, {-2.34291, 3.022, -0.0180339}, {-2.685, 2.38788, -0.0235241}, {-2.05673, 1.79845, -0.0197382}, {-1.43461, 1.35831, -0.0147852}, {-1.01977, 1.49519, -0.00524499}, {-0.657459, 1.70159, 0.00314672}, {-0.471469, 1.92739, 0.0090562}, {-0.271452, 2.17571, 0.0105406}, {-0.0544902, 2.4255, 0.00726066}, {0.088849, 2.65065, 0.00481318}, {-2.91779, 1.78813, 0.00554179}, {-2.76772, 2.0271, 0.0059156}, {-2.62836, 2.25476, 0.00609787}, {-2.49184, 2.46735, 0.00564363}, {-2.36378, 2.65907, 0.00520045}, {-2.15764, 2.79058, 0.00430346}, {-1.93681, 2.95711, 0.00379746}, {-1.74917, 3.17894, 0.00108206}, {-1.62065, 3.3892, -0.00243818}, {-1.54043, 3.53926, -0.00679947}, {-1.52667, 3.5603, -0.0115055}, {-1.56128, 3.36346, -0.0161056}, {-1.46727, 3.17649, -0.0188745}, {-1.13751, 3.0106, -0.018889}, {-0.884286, 2.85582, -0.0175313}, {-0.722335, 2.64545, -0.0130704}, {-0.676997, 2.36056, -0.00985928}, {-0.783757,1.97239, -0.00718945}, {-0.722798, 1.77166, -0.00450334}, {-0.529178, 1.72514, -0.00229542}, {-0.357731, 1.89902, 0.00113094}, {-0.187017,2.19689, 0.00519735}, {-0.0817395, 2.43165, 0.0049856}, {-3.4667, 1.47214, 0.00634143}, {-3.26824, 1.69635, 0.00694882}, {-3.05886, 1.92568, 0.00637995}, {-2.85447, 2.17101, 0.00540184}, {-2.71189, 2.31683, 0.00198414}, {-2.58939, 2.39888, -0.00251955}, {-2.27017, 2.39663, -0.00253107}, {-1.87509, 2.39241, -0.000912633}, {-1.54432, 2.48117, 0.000612044}, {-1.25389, 2.6328, 0.00139456}, {-1.16884, 2.73794, -0.00313543}, {-1.18723, 2.75041, -0.00981027}, {-0.941908,2.5932, -0.00994944}, {-0.564994, 2.31859, -0.00659007}, {-0.474841, 2.07871, -0.00223489}, {-0.496586, 1.86452, 0.0028551}, {-0.502707, 1.7399, 0.00113439}, {-0.521088, 1.65805, -0.0034519}, {-0.418778, 1.69707, -0.00299126}, {-0.266816, 1.77602, -0.00119712}, {-0.284312, 1.93475, 0.00207353}, {-0.341361, 2.11248, 0.00606308}, {-0.250744, 2.3092, 0.00466196}, {-3.99637, 1.04471, 0.00658444}, {-3.76389, 1.24075, 0.00673084}, {-3.50031, 1.41422, 0.00574592}, {-3.26121, 1.55861, 0.00372042}, {-3.14738, 1.61324, -0.00225626}, {-3.04123, 1.65048, -0.00816841}, {-2.64376, 1.72805, -0.00498186}, {-2.24255, 1.78348, -0.00182393}, {-1.86334, 1.88356, 0.00314933}, {-1.49523, 1.96151, 0.00755834}, {-1.33434, 2.06331, 0.00434038}, {-1.20887, 2.16909, 0.000257185}, {-0.874489, 2.127, 0.00136867}, {-0.520792, 2.10049, 0.00262757}, {-0.587071, 2.01632, 0.00366682}, {-0.672751, 1.91894, 0.00502246}, {-0.557456, 1.83835, 0.00265036}, {-0.434013, 1.7332, 0.000213548}, {-0.418396, 1.74205, 0.00467434}, {-0.402445, 1.75151, 0.00978354}, {-0.491712, 1.90388, 0.0081178}, {-0.586802, 2.06299, 0.0063321}, {-0.474316, 2.25156, 0.00376469}, {-4.47563, 0.580391, 0.0062851}, {-4.22643, 0.728446, 0.00600143}, {-3.97685, 0.903287, 0.0057512}, {-3.68716, 1.08062, 0.005445}, {-3.38939, 1.2601, 0.00478417}, {-3.10595, 1.32584, 0.00477534}, {-2.82544, 1.31075, 0.0051659}, {-2.5383, 1.31842, 0.00580437}, {-2.24398, 1.35606, 0.00712764}, {-1.96386, 1.45069, 0.00787434}, {-1.71298, 1.58551, 0.00724257}, {-1.45779, 1.67277, 0.00714269}, {-1.19492, 1.66543, 0.00802982}, {-0.987404, 1.63034, 0.00895786}, {-0.918053, 1.59862, 0.00937237}, {-0.855837, 1.58666, 0.00943676}, {-0.773169, 1.67133, 0.00827738}, {-0.713379, 1.75307, 0.00710789}, {-0.743972, 1.79634, 0.00660873}, {-0.775025, 1.84912, 0.00594295}, {-0.768565, 1.9708, 0.00423211}, {-0.76414, 2.09536, 0.00261564}, {-0.718174, 2.22923, 0.00195636}, {-4.84245, 0.0247128, 0.00663599}, {-4.60163, 0.134893, 0.00615977}, {-4.33722,0.213458, 0.00600669}, {-4.03095, 0.282612, 0.00670406}, {-3.72844,0.35898, 0.00757824}, {-3.4466, 0.525756, 0.00779127}, {-3.16458, 0.670256, 0.00809713}, {-2.87922, 0.805415, 0.00713277}, {-2.59957, 0.906162, 0.00650426}, {-2.3416, 1.02011, 0.0059111}, {-2.09427, 1.13693, 0.00527292}, {-1.86137, 1.25255, 0.00487388}, {-1.63452, 1.37635, 0.00445711}, {-1.4628, 1.47574, 0.00418248}, {-1.32232, 1.55229, 0.00402361}, {-1.21035, 1.62246, 0.00393886}, {-1.12571, 1.68206, 0.00393907}, {-1.06185, 1.74573, 0.00360047}, {-1.02662, 1.82402, 0.00272227}, {-0.99744, 1.90232, 0.00206707}, {-0.976116, 1.99337, 0.00179603}, {-0.954669, 2.08965, 0.00150697}, {-0.926833, 2.19888, 0.00143673}}


Is there any reason why you re-implement the Runge-Kutta method, while Mathematica has already very powerful NDSolve ?

@yarchik Well there really isn't a reason. I am new to Mathematica so I am not super familiar which functions I can use.

I recommend to use NDSolve for time-propagation. By default, it uses highly optimised adaptive step methods. Your propagation will be faster and you do not need to care about setting the proper time-step. This should solve your problem "I am having major issues when it comes to increasing time steps "

**Comments have been moved to chat.

This is a minimal working example just to illustrate how to use NDSolve as a main solver for this problem. In this example we compute trajectory for 100 particles with size distribution from $10^{-6}$ to $10^{-4}$ in the wind velocity with curl. To simulate drag force we use formula for drag coefficient from the paper
cD[re_] := 
 24/re (1 + .15 re^0.681) + .407/(1 + 8710/re);
delV = {{-4.84245`, 1.02015`}, {0.0247128`, 3.93786`}, {-0.0235241`, 
   0.0154004`}}; U[x_, y_, z_] := Mean[delV[[1]]] - y/1000; 
V[x_, y_, z_] := Mean[delV[[2]]] + x/1000; 
W[x_, y_, z_] := Mean[delV[[3]]];
numParticles = 100;
particleDensity = 1400;
fluidViscosity = 1.81*10^-5;
fluidDensity = 1.225;
particleDiameters = RandomReal[{10^-6, 10^-4}, numParticles];
particleRadii = particleDiameters/2;
particleMasses = particleDensity*(4/3)*Pi*particleRadii^3;

The particle distribution looks like
ListPlot[Sort[particleDiameters], Filling -> Axis]


To simulate particles dynamics we use NDSolve as follows
var = 
 Table[{x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]}, {i, numParticles}] // 
  Flatten; var1 = 
 Table[{x[i]'[t], y[i]'[t], z[i]'[t]}, {i, numParticles}] // Flatten;
eqs = Table[{x[i]''[t] == 
      0.5  Pi  particleRadii[[i]]^2*
       cD[particleDiameters[[i]]  Norm[{U[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]], 
             V[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]], 
             W[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]]} - {x[i]'[t], y[i]'[t], 
             z[i]'[t]}]/(fluidViscosity/fluidDensity)]*fluidDensity*
       Norm[{U[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]], 
           V[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]], 
           W[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]]} - {x[i]'[t], y[i]'[t], 
           z[i]'[t]}]/
        particleMasses[[i]] (U[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]] - x[i]'[t]),
      y[i]''[t] == 
      0.5  Pi  particleRadii[[i]]^2*
       cD[particleDiameters[[i]]  Norm[{U[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]], 
             V[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]], 
             W[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]]} - {x[i]'[t], y[i]'[t], 
             z[i]'[t]}]/(fluidViscosity/fluidDensity)]*fluidDensity*
       Norm[{U[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]], 
           V[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]], 
           W[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]]} - {x[i]'[t], y[i]'[t], 
           z[i]'[t]}]/
        particleMasses[[i]] (V[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]] - y[i]'[t]),
      z[i]''[t] == 
      0.5  Pi  particleRadii[[i]]^2*
        cD[particleDiameters[[i]]  Norm[{U[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]],
               V[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]], 
              W[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]]} - {x[i]'[t], y[i]'[t], 
              z[i]'[t]}]/(fluidViscosity/fluidDensity)]*fluidDensity*
        Norm[{U[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]], 
            V[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]], 
            W[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]]} - {x[i]'[t], y[i]'[t], 
            z[i]'[t]}]/
         particleMasses[[i]] (W[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]] - 
          z[i]'[t]) - 9.81}, {i, numParticles}] // Flatten;
ic = Table[{var[[i]] == 0, var1[[i]] == 0} /. t -> 0, {i, 
    Length[var]}];

sol = NDSolve[{eqs, ic}, var, {t, 0, 7200}]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[]= {0.496696, Null}

Note, that it takes half second only to compute 2 h run.
Visualization
ParametricPlot3D[
 Evaluate[
  Table[{x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]} /. sol[[1]], {i, 
    numParticles}]], {t, 0, 6000}] 


As we can see in the picture above a large particles coming to the ground in 2 h while small particles still float in the atmosphere.
Update 1 We can retrieve wind data from Mathematica base as follows (see this post)
Monitor[windvectordata = 
   Table[{GeoPosition[{i, j}], 
     WindVectorData[GeoPosition[{i, j}], 
      DateObject[{2024, 4, 18, 9}]]}, {i, 63, 
     67, .2}, {j, -26, -12, .2}];, {i, j}]

refLat = 63.63509;
refLon = -19.61262; ls = 
 ListStreamPlot[
  Cases[{Flatten[Reverse[#[[1, 1]]]], QuantityMagnitude[#[[2]]]} & /@ 
    Flatten[windvectordata, 1], {_, {_?NumberQ, _?NumberQ}}]];
arrows = Cases[ls, Arrow[_], Infinity];
GeoGraphics[{Red, Arrowheads[Small], arrows, Red, PointSize[Large], 
  Point[GeoPosition[{refLat, refLon}]]}, GeoBackground -> "ReliefMap"]


While the datum with time was taken randomly we see strong storm around reference point. It could be interesting to simulate particles dynamics in such flow. So we used model from above as follows
tab = Cases[{Flatten[Reverse[#[[1, 1]]]], 
     QuantityMagnitude[#[[2]]]} & /@ 
   Flatten[windvectordata, 1], {_, {_?NumberQ, _?NumberQ}}];metersPerDegreeLat = 111320;
metersPerDegreeLon[lat_] := 
 Cos[lat*Degree]*
  metersPerDegreeLat; grid = {(#[[1]] - refLon) metersPerDegreeLon[#[[
       2]]], (#[[2]] - refLat) metersPerDegreeLat} & /@ tab[[All, 1]];

2D flow velocity
{U2, V2} = 
  Table[Interpolation[Transpose[{grid, tab[[All, 2, i]]}], 
    InterpolationOrder -> 1], {i, 2}]; 

Trajectory computation
cD[re_] := 
 24/re (1 + .15 re^0.681) + .407/(1 + 
     8710/re);
delV = {{-4.84245`, 1.02015`}, {0.0247128`, 3.93786`}, {-0.0235241`, 
   0.0154004`}}; U[x_, y_, z_] := U2[x, y]; V[x_, y_, z_] := V2[x, y];
 W[x_, y_, z_] := Mean[delV[[3]]];
numParticles = 100;
particleDensity = 1400;
fluidViscosity = 1.81*10^-5;
fluidDensity = 1.225;
particleDiameters = Sort[RandomReal[{10^-6, 10^-4}, numParticles]];
particleRadii = particleDiameters/2;
particleMasses = particleDensity*(4/3)*Pi*particleRadii^3;
var = Table[{x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]}, {i, numParticles}] // 
  Flatten; var1 = 
 Table[{x[i]'[t], y[i]'[t], z[i]'[t]}, {i, numParticles}] // Flatten; 
getHeight[diameter_] := 
 Piecewise[{{3000, diameter < 15*10^-6}, {2750, 
    15*10^-6 <= diameter < 17.5*10^-6}, {2500, 
    17.5*10^-6 <= diameter < 20*10^-6}, {2250, 
    20*10^-6 <= diameter < 22.5*10^-6}, {2000, 
    22.5*10^-6 <= diameter}}]; tmax = 8 3600;
eqs = Table[{x[i]''[t] == 
      0.5 Pi particleRadii[[i]]^2*
       cD[particleDiameters[[
          i]] Norm[{U[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]], 
             V[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]], 
             W[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]]} - {x[i]'[t], y[i]'[t], 
             z[i]'[t]}]/(fluidViscosity/fluidDensity)]*fluidDensity*
       Norm[{U[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]], 
           V[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]], 
           W[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]]} - {x[i]'[t], y[i]'[t], 
           z[i]'[t]}]/
        particleMasses[[i]] (U[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]] - x[i]'[t]),
      y[i]''[t] == 
      0.5 Pi particleRadii[[i]]^2*
       cD[particleDiameters[[
          i]] Norm[{U[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]], 
             V[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]], 
             W[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]]} - {x[i]'[t], y[i]'[t], 
             z[i]'[t]}]/(fluidViscosity/fluidDensity)]*fluidDensity*
       Norm[{U[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]], 
           V[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]], 
           W[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]]} - {x[i]'[t], y[i]'[t], 
           z[i]'[t]}]/
        particleMasses[[i]] (V[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]] - y[i]'[t]),
      z[i]''[t] == 
      0.5 Pi particleRadii[[i]]^2*
        cD[particleDiameters[[
           i]] Norm[{U[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]], 
              V[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]], 
              W[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]]} - {x[i]'[t], y[i]'[t], 
              z[i]'[t]}]/(fluidViscosity/fluidDensity)]*fluidDensity*
        Norm[{U[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]], 
            V[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]], 
            W[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]]} - {x[i]'[t], y[i]'[t], 
            z[i]'[t]}]/
         particleMasses[[i]] (W[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]] - 
          z[i]'[t]) - 9.81}, {i, numParticles}] // Flatten;
ic = Table[{x[i][0] == 0, y[i][0] == 0, 
     z[i][0] == getHeight[particleDiameters[[i]]], 
     x[i]'[0] == RandomReal[{1, 10}], y[i]'[0] == RandomReal[{1, 10}],
      z[i]'[0] == RandomReal[{1, 10}]}, {i, numParticles}] // Flatten;

It takes about 25s to finish 8h run for 100 particles in this flow
sol = NDSolve[{eqs, ic}, var, {t, 0, tmax}]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[]= {24.5662, Null}

Projection of trajectories on a region
convertToGeo[{xMeters_, yMeters_, z_}, latRef_, lonRef_] := 
  Module[{latDeg, lonDeg}, latDeg = yMeters/metersPerDegreeLat; 
   lonDeg = 
    xMeters/metersPerDegreeLon[latRef + latDeg]; {latRef + latDeg, 
    lonRef + lonDeg, z}];
trajectories = 
  Table[Table[{x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]} /. sol[[1]], {t, 0, tmax, 
     100}], {i, numParticles}];
geoTrajectories = 
  Map[convertToGeo[#, refLat, refLon] &, trajectories, {2}];

GeoGraphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], 
  Point[GeoPosition[{refLat, refLon}]], {Black, PointSize[Medium], 
   Point[GeoPosition[#]] & /@ geoTrajectories}}, 
 GeoRange -> {{63, 67}, {-26, -12}}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 Frame -> True, GeoGridLines -> Automatic]
 


We also can simulate deposition dependence on the local elevation as follows
dataEl = 
  Table[GeoElevationData[
      GeoPosition[geoTrajectories[[i]][[All, 1 ;; 2]]]] // Normal // 
    QuantityMagnitude, {i, numParticles}];

Do[Do[If[
    geoTrajectories[[i]][[j - 1, 3]] - dataEl[[i]][[j - 1]] > 0 && 
     geoTrajectories[[i]][[j, 3]] - dataEl[[i]][[j]] < 0, 
    lastgeoPosition[i] = geoTrajectories[[i]][[j - 1]]], {j, 2, 
    Length[dataEl[[i]]]}];, {i, numParticles}]
dataLGP = 
  Select[Table[lastgeoPosition[i], {i, numParticles}], 
   NumericQ[Norm[#]] &];
GeoGraphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], 
  Point[GeoPosition[{refLat, refLon}]], {Black, PointSize[Medium], 
   Point[GeoPosition[#]] & /@ dataLGP}}, 
 GeoRange -> {{63.3, 64.5}, {-22, -19}}, ImageSize -> 400, 
 Frame -> True, GeoGridLines -> Automatic] 


Finally note, that we can extrapolate windvectordata at initial getHeight data using my atmospheric turbulence model described in the book and paper here, here, and here.

I have added a new piece of code that I was working on. I will try and take some of your insights to see if I can improve upon mine

Would it be possible to know what you mean when the grid is unstructured? Do you simply mean that I do not have enough grid points?

@Miguel To generate mesh for 3D region we first should define region. In your example there are points only without region definition. Also 3D mesh should involve altitude in some manner over ground, not over see level. How wind velocity filed has been reconstructed?  Is it some numerical model?

Ah I see then. In terms of the data, it was a colleague of mine who handled it, and as far as I know he downloaded it from NASA and then cleaned the data, and then provided me the file

@Miguel Please, see Update 1 to my answer.

Could you explain a few terms within your code - delV, U2, V2 and W, as I am not entirely sure why you have defined these.
Furthermore, it seems that when using the Update 1 code it is outputting errors, with the sol variable not being calculated, and its subsequent steps

@Miguel Sorry,  lines with grid and U2,V2 definitions have been uploaded.

Code works great, and I have adjusted it towards my project needs. I would just like to ask you, if there are major issues with the WhenEvents within the NDSolve, and even in your simulation when a z barrier of 0 is reached, and negative values take place, the event does not seem to trigger

@Miguel Do you mean how add WhenEvent to my code to simulate particle deposition at z=0?  Please note that in my second code there is  GeoElevationData used to simulate deposition at z=local elevation.

No. What I meant was for the WhenEvent condition to stop the calculation of the trajectory of particles when going under the z = 0 bound. So for example, with a diameter particle of 10^-2, and imposing a height of 100m, by simulating it over a predefined tmax of 1000s, the last z position within the geoTrajectory is of -52231.9. My idea would be to cap this within the equations before the NDSolve as to save computational time, but it seems to not trigger. Hopefully, that clears up what I meant

@Miguel We can't save computation time since we simulate 100 trajectories, and not 1. So we should compute all trajectories and then use some block to analyze deposition points for every particle size. As it shown in my example.

Whilst I was waiting for your comment, I was able to indeed make something work within the NDSolve myself. Here is the code that I have at the moment
(*Constants and initial conditions*)
g = 9.81; (*Gravity in m/s^2*)
numParticles = 1; (*Number of particles*)
tmax = 1000; (*Total time of simulation in seconds*)

(*Reference latitude and longitude*)
refLat = 63.63509; (*Volcano latitude*)
refLon = -19.61262; (*Volcano longitude*)
latRange = {63, 67};  (*Latitude range for Iceland*)
lonRange = {-26, -12};  (*Longitude range for Iceland*)

metersPerDegreeLat = 111320;
(* METERS PER DEGREE OF LONGITUDE *)
metersPerDegreeLon[lat_] := Cos[lat*Degree]*metersPerDegreeLat;  

(* FUNCTION TO CONVERT PARTICLES, TO START AT THE REFERENCE LATITUDE AND LONGITUDE *)
convertToGeo[{xMeters_, yMeters_, z_}, latRef_, lonRef_] := Module[{latDeg, lonDeg},latDeg = yMeters/metersPerDegreeLat;lonDeg = xMeters/metersPerDegreeLon[latRef]; {latRef + latDeg, lonRef + lonDeg, z}];

(*Material properties*)
rhoMaterial = 1400; (*Density of the material in kg/m^3,e.g.,Aluminum*)
rhoAir = 1.225; (*Density of air at sea level in kg/m^3*)
muAir = 1.81*10^-5; (*Dynamic viscosity of air at 25°C in Pa.s*)

(*Randomizing radius for each particle and sorting by size *)
radii = Sort[RandomReal[{12.5*10^-6, 25*10^-6}, numParticles]];
(*Masses of particles based on volume and density*)
masses = rhoMaterial*(4/3)*Pi*radii^3; 
(*Calculate terminal velocity for each particle*)
terminalVelocities = (2*radii^2*g*(rhoMaterial - rhoAir))/(9*muAir);

(*Modified drag force function to include terminal velocity*)
stokesDragForce[v_, r_, vt_] := Min[6*Pi*muAir*r*v, 6*Pi*muAir*r*vt];
(*Generate a constant wind vector field*)
windVectors = Flatten[Table[{{x, y, zHeight}, RandomReal[{10, 25}, 3]}, {x, 63, 
 67, 0.5}, {y, -26, -12, 2}, {zHeight, {1750, 2500}}], 2];
(*Wind influence calculation with three-dimensional effect*)
windInfluence[x_, y_, z_] := Module[{distances, forces}, distances = #1 - {x, y, z} & /@ windVectors[[All, 1]];forces = (1/(Norm[#]^2 + 1) & /@ distances)*windVectors[[All, 2]];Total[forces]];

(*Height assignment based on diameter*)
getHeight[diameter_] := Piecewise[{{ 3000, 12.5*10^-6 <= diameter < 15*10^-6}, { 2750, 15*10^-6 <= diameter < 17.5*10^-6}, {2500, 17.5*10^-6 <= diameter < 20*10^-6}, {2250, 20*10^-6 <= diameter < 22.5*10^-6}, {2000, 22.5*10^-6 <= diameter <= 25*10^-6}}];

(*Assign initial heights directly to reference latitude and longitude*) 
initialPositions = Table[{refLat, refLon, getHeight[radii[[i]]]}, {i, numParticles}];

(*Generating randomized initial velocities*)
initialVelocities = Table[{RandomReal[{1, 10}], RandomReal[{1, 10}], 
RandomReal[{1, 10}]}, {i, numParticles}];

(*Differential equations with drag effect and wind considering terminal velocity*)
equations = Flatten[Table[{x[i]''[t] == -stokesDragForce[x[i]'[t], radii[[i]], 
      terminalVelocities[[i]]]/masses[[i]] + windInfluence[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]][[1]], y[i]''[t] == -stokesDragForce[y[i]'[t], radii[[i]], terminalVelocities[[i]]]/masses[[i]] + windInfluence[x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]][[2]], z[i]''[t] == -g - stokesDragForce[z[i]'[t], radii[[i]], terminalVelocities[[i]]]/masses[[i]], x[i][0] == initialPositions[[i, 1]], x[i]'[0] == initialVelocities[[i, 1]], y[i][0] == initialPositions[[i, 2]], y[i]'[0] == initialVelocities[[i, 2]], z[i][0] == initialPositions[[i, 3]], z[i]'[0] == initialVelocities[[i, 3]]}, {i, numParticles}]];

(*Solve the differential equations*)
solution = NDSolve[equations, Flatten[Table[{x[i], y[i], z[i]}, {i, numParticles}]], {t, 0, tmax}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"];

(*Color list for each particle trajectory*)
colors = ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[1 ;; numParticles]];
(*Trajectory of the particles adjusted for geographic coordinates*)
trajectoriesMeters = Table[Table[{x[i][t], y[i][t], z[i][t]} /. First[solution], {t, 0, tmax, tmax/100}], {i, numParticles}];

(*Convert trajectories from meters to geographic coordinates*)
geoTrajectories = Map[convertToGeo[#, refLat, refLon] &, trajectoriesMeters, {2}];

(*Create GeoPaths from the converted trajectories*)
geoParticlePaths = Table[{colors[[i]], GeoPath[geoTrajectories[[i, All, {1,2}]]]},{i, numParticles}];

(*Display combined trajectories on one GeoGraphics*)
GeoGraphics[{geoParticlePaths, {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[GeoPosition[{refLat, refLon}]]}}, GeoRange -> {latRange, lonRange}, ImageSize -> Large, Frame -> True, GeoGridLines -> Automatic]

(*GeoGraphics with Wind Field and Volcano*)
GeoGraphics[{{Black, PointSize[Small], Point[GeoPosition /@ windVectors[[All, 1]]]}, {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[GeoPosition[{refLat, refLon}]]}}, GeoRange -> {latRange, lonRange}, ImageSize -> Large, Frame -> True, GeoGridLines -> Automatic]

I am just currently having a few problems with what I assume are the conversions in the latitude and longitude. Independently of this, you were definitely right in using an NDSolve, because with the old code I was having to wait for over 2 minutes to simulate a single particle moving, and now it is taking less than 1 second.

It looks like you try to simulate particles dynamics in mixed coordinate system used in geography, where horizontal coordinates are latitude and longitude, while altitude is in meters. Note, that we have nice tools to convert any reference point p to 3D Cartesian geocentric coordinates  GeoPositionXYZ[p] and vise verse to (lat, lon, alt) with GeoPosition.

@AlexTrounev The idea is to convert the latitude and longitude into meters, so every calculation can be done in meters, and then subsequently reverse so I can plot it. Unfortunately, I am not entirely sure what I am doing wrong at the moment, as I have converted the necessary data into meters, but the particle is not moving at a realistic pace

In the initial data use zero x, y as initialPositions =    Table[{0, 0, getHeight[radii[[i]]]}, {i, numParticles}], since in convertToGeo[#, refLat, refLon]  you used refLat, refLon as initial position on the map.

@AlexTrounev I have tried that, but for some reason, the particle just does not seem to move in latitude and longitude, which does not make sense.
If you run the code above, you will see that for a time of 1000s, and a radius of 16*10^-6, the trajectory of the particle would come down to the following
{63.6351, -19.6126, 2750.}, {63.6351, -19.6126, 2751.39}, ... {63.6351, -19.6126, 2594.36}, {63.6351, -19.6126, 2594.31}

With wind speed of about 1m/s particles run distance of about 1 km in 1000s. Why not to use ParametricPlot3D to see trajectory?  Your model has a typo. Please, use my model to test your model.

@AlexTrounev I will try and use a ParametricPlot3D to see the trajectory. However, the code stems from me testing a 3D plot, where the particle was indeed moving in a lower scale.
Even by testing, it seems that the particle is somehow only moving around 100 meters in both lat and long directions
